# How do I trigger toggling of an element with another on former element's hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 buttons, `a`, and `b` that I want to toggle on hover of `a` but it keeps blinking in between because I think once `a` disappears, it triggers the mouseexit.

They both have the same display position.

```js
$('#a').hover(
  function() {
    $('#a').css("display", "none")
    $('#b').css("display", "block")
  },
  function() {
    $('#a').css("display", "block")
    $('#b').css("display", "none")
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <i id="a" class="a" style="position: absolute; right: 48px; top: 30px; width: 24px;">A</i>
  <i id="b" class="b" style="display: none; position: absolute; right: 48px; top: 30px; width: 24px;">B</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```js
$('#a').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#b').show();
});
$('#b').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#a').show();
});
```

```css
#b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="a">A</button>
<button id="b">B</button>
```